# Como pegar a data que o usuário colocou no calendário?

Tags: android

Eu estou fazendo um programa no qual precisa que o usuário coloque a data de seu compromisso, e o que acontece meu aplicativo vai mandar uma notificação pra ele dois dias antes do compromisso para que o usuário lembre de seu compromisso.

**Primeiramente** eu queria saber como eu faço para pegar o calendário na classe java.

**Depois** como eu faço para pegar a data que o usuário colocou no calendário.

**E se possível** vocês poderia tentar me mostrar como eu faço para que o aplicativo verifique a data e quando estiver dois dias antes ele passa uma notificação.

Obrigado!

Comment: Quando você diz calendário seria o Widget `DatePicker` (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) ou aplicativo Calendário?

Comment: o Widget DatePicker.

Comment: Já chegou a configurar o layout com o `DatePicker`?

Comment: Sim já, mais não muito por isso não entendo muito bem ainda de data no android..

Comment: Quando inflar o layout, basta recuperar a instância do widget e usar a API do `DatePicker` para recuperar a data selecionada, no caso é só usar o `DatePicker.getCalendarView().getDate())` e construir um Objeto `Calendar` do Java com esse retorno para manipular a data. A data no Android usa a mesma API de data do Java. A dúvida talvez é diferenciar o widget que é da API gráfica do Android, dos objetos Date/Calendar que é da API Java.

Comment: Ok, mais como eu faria para mandar uma notificação dois dias antes da data ?

Comment: Isso pode ser feito usando o `AlarmManager`. Você pode registrar um `Intent` para uma determinada hora/dia, onde um `BroadcastReceiver` seu será notificado. Ai existem diversas configurações que podem ser feitas, basta dar uma olhada a fundo na API do `AlarmManager`.

Comment: Beleza vou tentar lá obrigado!